# My Salesforce stackexchange profile seems reset?

Tags: support, bug, badges, reputation

My [Salesforce stackexchange profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/38952/pasan-eeriyagama) seems being reset after I added my peronal email address as a new login. My personal email had a profile before, but I had deleted it, and added the email to new one (Which I used the most).

It ended up with incorrect badges, reputation. Can anyone help to fix this for me please. I tried to contact their support, but got no response yet after a day. Appreciate any help on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Contacting support is all you can do. Moderators can't help you here, and neither can any other users. It's not likely the Community Managers can or will help you either, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, hoping some answer from them.